# Using Python with Visual Studio-Installig Python2.7.9 damaged Python27 (ImportError: No module named site)

Tags: python

Seems that I got myself into trouble. I was running Python27 from Eclipse. Because the Eclipse debugger did not work, no matter what I did and because I accidentally found out that Visual Studio might work with CPython I decided to give it a try. So I installed VS 2013 and because I could not find Python as an option to start a project (I actually searched in the wrong place) I thought that installing CPython from http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation will fix that. When I installed Python 2.7.9 did not notice that that Python was the x32 version while my already installed Python 27 was x64.
Because the existing Python27 had some modules installed, Visual studio (which was now using Python2.7.9 x32) could not run my sources written in Eclipse. So ..Visual Studio did not work for me. When I checked to see if Eclipse was still fine I got the error **ImportError: No module named site**

So right now I have two IDEs that are not working at all and if I try to run Python27 from the command line I get the above error again?

What can I do to fix Python27 to work as it used to work before? I hope that this will fix Eclipse as well.
BTW, installing CPython renamed C:\Python27\python.exe to python2.exe I think that some paths were also modified but C:\Python27 is still in PATH so I don't know what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed by uninstalling Python 2.7.9 and using the installer for Python 2.7 (more precisely it was Python 2.7.8 x64) to fix this installation. The modules installed there were preserved